# How to use "the first thing, not the second" construction?

Tags: phrase

I need to use a couple verbal turns. The first looks like '*to open the bottle, not the box*', the second does not seem correct to me but probably in German it will work better: '*to open not the box, but the bottle*'.

So should the verb go in the end of the sentence or in the end of the first clause? How to say it all better? What about punctuation?

> Es war notwendig, nicht die Flasche zu entdecken, aber den Kasten.

or

> Es war notwendig, nicht die Flasche aber den Kasten zu entdecken.

Comment: If your German examples are meant as translations of the English ones: why did you choose to translate _open_ with _entdecken_? Also: could you give more context, please? I don't understand what you want to express.

Comment: I need a verb that can replace another one in the following phrases: 'discover the secret' and 'open the bottle'. _entdecken_ is the only probably. Context: 'Many philosophers realized too late that it was necessary to open the bottles, not the secrets'. I write a text about _schwarzgebranntes_.

Comment: @aftermag So you are essentially looking for a verb that can express "open a bottle" and "reveal a secret", to translate that word play, right? I'm afraid _entdecken_ won't do this. And you should rephrase your question, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: The context for the "secrets" is still missing, but if a single verb is not working, just use two: Viele Philosophen verstanden zu spät, dass man lieber die Flaschen öffnen soltte, statt die Geheimnisse aufzudecken. (Though "aufdecken" might be the wrong verb; as I said, the context is missing). "Notwendig" makes the construction clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct, except that you should go with *sondern* instead of *aber*. In the sense of *rather* (*not ... but ...*), you translate *but* as *sondern*.
This is also true for your second sentence. That sentence, however, additionally misses a comma. Always [put a comma before sondern](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Aufzaehlung.html#Anchor-Vor-49575). And also before *aber*.

> Es war notwendig, nicht die Flasche, sondern den Kasten zu öffnen.

That being said, using "man musste" sounds more natural to me:

> Man musste die Flasche öffnen, (aber) nicht den Kasten.
>   Man musste nicht die Flasche öffnen, sondern den Kasten.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace »aber« by »sondern«:

> Es war notwendig nicht die Flasche zu entdecken, sondern den Kasten.

Also correct:

> Es war notwendig nicht die Flasche, sondern den Kasten zu entdecken.

In english:

> It was necessary not to discover the bottle, but the box.